# how can I get email and password at the same time methop post laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I would like to get the email and password when I call AuthController@login method but there isn't in the controller.

My proyect : I want to save all activity from login , the bad passwords , bad email , how many time the user tried to enter to the system and the corrects logins of course .

My model UserActivity have this attributes: email,password,datetime .
I would like to create a new variable and save it `userActivity->save()`; when I call the POST method login.

I use

```
php artisan make:auth
```

but in the AuthController.php i only found that functions.

```
function __construct
function validator
function create
```

but i got that route with php artisan route:list command

```
POST | login | | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@login | web,guest |
```

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

(I created laravel login this way because is easier, but i want to do only that diferent. Sorry my English is bad) .

Answer (score 0):

There is method `postLogin` in `Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php` which can be overwritten.

Eg in `AuthController` add:

```
/**
 * Handle a login request to the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
    return parent::postLogin($request);
}
```

Comment: Sorry,  but when I login,  the dd()  instruction didn't work,  so I can't found the step where can I get the email and password immediately I start POST login method

Comment: Did You paste that method into `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController` ??

Comment: Yes , I paste the method in App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php file , between Validator and Create function , the dd() method have to interrupt the normal secuence of the login and show me de attributes , but , I log in without any interruption.